# Annotating a list of fields instead of a single field with lombok v 0.9.2

Tags: java, lombok

In an effort to generate less boilerplate code I'm using lombok annotations.  I had hoped to create even less boilerplate code by annotating a list of fields like so

```
@Getter @Setter
private String a, b, c, d, e ... z;
```

But the annotation only appears to affect the first field in the list.  Is there a way to make it affect the whole list without seperating it out like

```
@Getter @Setter
private String a;

@Getter @Setter
private String b;
```

Note that I can't annotate the class as there are a bunch of fields that need limited access and and some fields that I only want getter access for.  Basically, I'm looking for some analog in java to ruby's `attr_accessor` type list which is pretty awesome.

**UPDATE**

This is failing on the ant build with the 1.12.6 lombok.  I tested a simple case with the 1.12.6 lombok version and it works.  It's hard to tell where in my code this is being tickled as we use lombok extensively throughout the project and the stack trace doesn't mention anything in our code.

java versions:

```
jimi@Immaculate:/web/project/XXXXX.com$ javac -version
javac 1.6.0-internal
jimi@Immaculate:/web/project/XXXXX.com$ java -version
java version "1.6.0"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build pxi3260sr13ifix-20130303_02(SR13+IV37419))
IBM J9 VM (build 2.4, JRE 1.6.0 IBM J9 2.4 Linux x86-32 jvmxi3260sr13-20130114_134867 (JIT enabled, AOT enabled)
J9VM - 20130114_134867
JIT  - r9_20130108_31100
GC   - 20121212_AA)
JCL  - 20130303_02
```

Stack trace:

```
    [javac] Consult the following stack trace for details.
    [javac] java.lang.NullPointerException
    [javac]     at java.util.IdentityHashMap$IdentityHashMapEntry.setValue(IdentityHashMap.java:135)
    [javac]     at lombok.javac.apt.Processor.process(Processor.java:261)
    [javac]     at lombok.core.AnnotationProcessor$JavacDescriptor.process(AnnotationProcessor.java:117)
    [javac]     at lombok.core.AnnotationProcessor.process(AnnotationProcessor.java:167)
    [javac]     at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.callProcessor(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:639)
    [javac]     at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.discoverAndRunProcs(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:568)
    [javac]     at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.doProcessing(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:713)
    [javac]     at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.processAnnotations(JavaCompiler.java:999)
    [javac]     at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.compile(JavaCompiler.java:739)
    [javac]     at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:365)
    [javac]     at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:291)
    [javac]     at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:282)
    [javac]     at com.sun.tools.javac.Main.compile(Main.java:81)
    [javac]     at com.sun.tools.javac.Main.main(Main.java:66)
```

Comment: I'm using lombok version 0.9.2. I'll probably upgrade as has been suggested and try that.

Comment: upgraded to 1.12.6, but that is failing to compile with an NPE

Comment: To summarize, it is not working for me in 0.9.2, but it is working in 1.12.6.  I wasn't able to use it in my project due to compile errors, but I'm sure it would be good in any new projects.

Comment: You mentioned an NPE. Is that in Lombok? Do you use jdk8? The upcoming release has fixed a problem with @SneakyThrows in combination with jdk8. Disclosure: I am one of the Project Lombok developers.

Comment: Yeah, the NPE was coming from Lombok.  We are still using IBM's jdk6 for this legacy app.  I can probably re-install 1.12.6 and get you a stack trace, if you like.

Comment: Please do so. If it is an old IBM compiler I cannot promise that we'll fix it. Please include a [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://www.sscce.org/)

Comment: @Roel Spiker I updated the question with a stack trace and java versions.  I don't know that I can get a simple example pulled out of the project since it is very large and I don't know exactly which part is causing the issue. Maybe you could point me somewhere based on the lombok portion of the stack trace?

Comment: I've reopened [issue 544](https://code.google.com/p/projectlombok/issues/detail?id=554)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd bet it's meant to apply to all the fields. And for me it indeed works like this: I've got a bunch of getters and setters when I copied your example.

There may be a Lombok bug for the compiler you're using. File a bug with all the details.

### UPDATE

Chapter 8.3 of the [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3) says it clearly:

> More than one field may be declared in a single field declaration by using more than one declarator; the FieldModifiers and Type apply to all the declarators in the declaration.

It works for me with both Eclipse and Gradle. I'm using Lombok 1.12.7 (more precisely, commit e890428 from 2014-05-01), but this really shouldn't matter. I can't see any such change since 1.12.6 and I'd bet it's been always meant to work the "right" way.

Comment: I'll update my lombok version and see if that helps.

Comment: I'm building via an ant task, so eclipse is irrelevant in this case, though I'm coding in eclipse.

Comment: Which version of lombok are you using?  I would get getters and setters for the first in the list and that's it.

Comment: I have confirmed it is working as expected with the latest lombok.  Too bad I can't use it on my project.  :(

Comment: @JimiKimble Maybe you should ask on the Lombok mailing list about the change. I'd suppose it was just a temporary glitch, but according to what you wrote it wasn't. The [changelog](http://projectlombok.org/changelog.html) lets us hope that a new official version is soon to come.

Comment: Since the version where it isn't working is pretty ancient, I'm inclined to say just upgrade if you need this fixed.  There seem to be some upgrade issues for the project I'm on with lombok and I don't want to deal with them right now, so I've separated the 30 or so fields out.  No biggie.   Thanks for your help on this one.